# Calculating gene separation -a genetics problem

Tags: genetics, homework, chromosome, quantitative-genetics, genetic-linkage

I am really struggling with genetics. In particular, I have the following question

[image]

Now I am OK with calculating the separation of genes in centrimorgans when I have data like so:

[image]

But in the first question, I am not sure if this is even possible. I gone through many books to no avail.

The conclusions I have been able to draw so far are:

- these mutations are carried on X due to similar proportions of males and females exhibiting the characteristics.
- the order of genes seems to be white, miniature, forked due to white miniature and forked miniature occurring much more frequently than white forked. Also it seems that white and miniature genes are close than miniature and forked as the former is a more commonly exhibited phenotype.

All of this is alluding to me somehow being able to figure out the separation of the genes, but I do not know how. Or if this is at all possible in this problem..

Comment: Text on images are not very welcome. These texts are not searchable and cause problems for people with visual impairments.

Comment: Your second image appears completely black on my browser. @Remi.b is right, you should take the trouble to set out your question properly otherwise I shall vote to close.